# How to Activate a File Drop Triggered Automation through the API

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigger, api, automationstudio, automation

This question has been asked a few times over the years but has yet to receive an answer.

I am trying to figure out how to activate a file drop triggered automation through the API(Changing it from "Inactive" to "Active"). I can create these automations through both REST and SOAP but the essential task of activating them has eluded me.

It is not explained in the official documentation and I have yet to find an answer anywhere else, but I do believe it is possible somehow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately as it stands right now there is no way to do this utilizing the public SFMC API (neither SOAP nor REST). You, as an end user will need to utilize the UI to activate/deactivate a file drop Automation.

There is an internal rest endpoint (use developer tools on your browser, click on network tab in dev tools and then toggle your automation off/on) that you can find in the UI, but the authentication required to access that is not available outside of SFMC.

I have investigated all the available documented and undocumented endpoints and none are able to make this change. You can view the status inside of the API, but any PATCH or Update made to it will not change this. I have attempted doing an 'Execute', 'Schedule', 'Perform', etc. to try and change the status (similar to how you can turn on a scheduled automation or 'run once') but to no avail.

I have been championing this lack of functionality for a while, but have had no progress reported back to me on any solution for it.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer Gortonington, it is disappointing this is not available. One possible work around I've been thinking about would be to create a sort of template automation that has already been activated manually, then duplicating and updating that automation via the API each time you need to create a new active automation. Unfortunately I don't believe you can duplicate automations through the API, have you heard or seen anything otherwise?

Comment: You can sort of duplicate an automation through retrieve and create (its not a simple process) but the activation/schedule will not be able to be kept as active. I feel like the SOAP object 'FileTrigger' is the key, but I can find no way to actually utilize it to activate any automation.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was playing with triggered automations from azure blob storage and the api call used for the activation was a PATCH to https://mc.sXXXX.marketingcloudapps.com/AutomationStudioFuel3/fuelapi/automation/v1/automations/trigger/automationLegacyId
With a JSON body: {"isActive":false/true}
(The automationLegacyId can be retrieved from the url or via API).
So I changed the host to my own tenant and it worked!

The endpoint now looks like:

PATCH

https://tenant.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/trigger/automationLegacyId

body:{"isActive":false/true}

Now I can fully automate some processes without having to manually activate the automations. Hope you can too.